# Best method to sense low temperatures while using low current

Tags: temperature, thermocouple, rtd

I need to measure temperatures of -80C, and the circuit needs to be battery-powered. So I thought an RTD probe with the MAX31865 RTD-to-Digital Converter would work well. I am using an nRF52840 for a microcontroller.

I got the circuit working, but unfortunately, the standby current of the MAX31865 is 700uA. This is way to high for my application, I missed this on the datasheet when I purchased it...

My first thought was to use an I/O pin to power on the chip when I needed a reading, then power it off when I am done. The problem presented here is that I have other SPI chips on my board, and this (I believe) damaged the MAX31865 by having the power disconnected while SPI communication was still happening. I can't confirm this, but after reading a bit on this topic it seems likely that this is the culprit.

My next thought is to use a buffer chip to connect/disconnect the power and SPI on the MAX31865, but I feel like there is a simpler solution somewhere here.

Does anyone know how to reduce the standby current of the MAX31865?
If not, is there a solution that can safely power down the chip when not in use?

Or potentially a better setup entirely.
I read up on thermocouples, but they don't seem to be recommended for very low temperatures, mostly very high temperatures.

Comment: thermocouples will work at low temperatures.  I have used K-type at -80C. (Dry-ice alcohol mixture)

Comment: this site is not a forum ... it is a question and answer site ... please do not ask multiple questions that cannot be answered with one answer

Comment: @RussellH what type of accuracy were you getting at -80C ?

Comment: @jsotola I hope my post bothers you as much as it appears to.

Comment: @MattG it does not bother me even one bit ... I'm just trying to prevent the question from being closed for not being focused

Comment: one option would be to use a buffer chip between the rest of the system and the thermocouple chip.  something like LVC which is not harmed by inputs while powered off.